# Error in nls: fator de passos 4.65661e-10 reduzido abaixo de 'minFactor' de 9.31323e-10

Tags: r

Estou tentando rodar um análise "nls", mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> "fator de passos 4.65661e-10 reduzido abaixo de 'minFactor' de
>   9.31323e-10"

Estou usando os seguintes conjuntos de dados e fórmula:

```
n.kill<-c(79,4,86,9,10,49,45,260,10,8,182,16,824,2,11,112)
body<-c(160,1.5,23,40,4.5,4.5,0.8,3,1.2,60,70,0.5,35,30.5,4,47)
df<-data.frame(n.kill, body)
ca=max(df$n.kill)

fun=nls(n.kill~a*(1-exp(-b*body))^c, data=df, start=list(a=ca, b=0.05, c=1), 
  algorithm='plinear', control=nls.control(maxiter = 10000, minFactor = (1/2)^30))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com os dados do problema, as seguintes modificações

- Reduzir `maxiter` para 100;
- incluir `tol = eps`, com `eps = .Machine$double.eps^0.5`;
- Usar o algoritmo `'port'` em vez de `'plinear'`.

conseguiram convergência em 11 iterações.

```
eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
fit <- nls(n.kill ~ a*(1 - exp(-b*body))^c, data = df, 
           start = list(a = ca, b = 0.05, c = 1), 
           #trace = TRUE,
           algorithm = 'port', 
           control = nls.control(maxiter = 100, tol = eps))

summary(fit)
#
#Formula: n.kill ~ a * (1 - exp(-b * body))^c
#
#Parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#a 162.8666    87.9631   1.852   0.0869 .
#b   0.1173     0.7910   0.148   0.8844  
#c   0.7839     3.4292   0.229   0.8227  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 210.8 on 13 degrees of freedom
#
#Algorithm "port", convergence message: relative convergence (4)
```

Comment: Certo, Rui. Muito obrigado pelas correções.

Comment: @MiltondePaula O que fazer quando [alguém responde](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) às suas perguntas.